# Why doesn't PHP's preg_replace function like escaping "\"?

Tags: php, regex

I use the [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) website to test my regular expressions.  On that website it can easily find the character "\" with the RegEx string `/\\/g`.  But when I use it in php it throws back:

> Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '/'

**My Code**

```
$str = "0123456789 _+-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>";

echo preg_replace('/\\/', '', $str);
```

Why doesn't PHP like to escape "\"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using it in the regexp use `\\` to use it in the replacement, use `\\\\`  will turn into `\\` that will be interpreted as a single backslash.

Use it like this:

```
<?php
$str = "0123456789 _+-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>";
echo preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $str);
```

Output:

```
0123456789 _+-.,!@#$%^&*();/|<>
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no difference between `\\ `  and `\ `  with regular use in the preg_replace function? meaning `/\+/` and `/\\+/` would act identical?

Comment: `/\+/` will escape `+` and what is this: `\//+\`

Comment: Yeah acts identical!

Comment: That's really weird.  Thanks for your help.